# Does Ubuntu keep a backup of /home folder?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, home-directory, rm

I am running Ubuntu-server-16.04 in VirtualBox. I was trying to delete a folder in home directory and instead of running:

```
rm -rf folder_name
```

I run:

```
rm -rf *
```

and deleted everything.

This maybe wishful thinking but does Ubuntu somehow keep a backup of home folder?

Comment: No, unless you set backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Creating a backup is a task for the owner of the system or the owner of the data.

Using it in a virtual system you should regularly make backups of that system. It takes seconds to copy one.

You can even automate the backup from the main OS so you have a daily backup.

Comment: Well 'live and learn', I guess. Thankfully none of the config files were deleted.